# Why doesn't the homepage of SE sites explain what the site is for?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com, scope, homepage

I finally got tired of scrolling through [the site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) and created [a note](https://www.evernote.com/l/ABLn2Hp3uJJM_5sDOYcuwDVY088SWxxMMog) to remind me.

My goal is to not post questions to the wrong community. I find deciding between Super User vs. Stack Overflow and Super User vs. Server Fault to be particularly challenging. I always refer back to the phrasing.

I think it would help with the quality and relevance of questions if both the `/` and `/questions/ask` for each site included the blurb shown on the sites list.

**Why doesn't the root (and 'ask') page of SE sites explain what the site is for?**

The site descriptions are quite good and worth displaying...

- Stack Overflow - Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
- Server Fault - Q&A for system and network administrators
- Super User - Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users
- Meta Stack Exchange - Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites
- Web Applications - Q&A for power users of web applications
- Arqade - Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms
- Webmasters - Q&A for pro webmasters
- Seasoned Advice - Q&A for professional and amateur chefs
- Game Development - Q&A for professional and independent game developers
- Photography - Q&A for professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers
- Cross Validated - Q&A for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization
- Mathematics - Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields
- Home Improvement - Q&A for contractors and serious DIYers
- Geographic Information Systems - Q&A for cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals
- TeX - LaTeX - Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems
- Ask Ubuntu - Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers
  Personal Finance & Money - Q&A for people who want to be financially literate
- English Language & Usage - Q&A for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts
- Stack Apps - Q&A for apps, scripts, and development with the Stack Exchange API
- User Experience - Q&A for user experience researchers and experts
- Unix & Linux - Q&A for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems
- WordPress Development - Q&A for WordPress developers and administrators
- Theoretical Computer Science - Q&A for theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields
- Ask Different - Q&A for power users of Apple hardware and software
- Role-playing Games - Q&A for gamemasters and players of tabletop, paper-and-pencil role-playing games
- Bicycles - Q&A for people who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles
- Software Engineering - Q&A for professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly
- Electrical Engineering - Q&A for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts
- Android Enthusiasts - Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system
- Board & Card Games - Q&A for people who like playing board games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing board games
- Physics - Q&A for active researchers, academics and students of physics
- Homebrewing - Q&A for dedicated home brewers and serious enthusiasts
- Information Security - Q&A for information security professionals
- Writers - Q&A for authors, editors, reviewers, professional writers, and aspiring writers
- Video Production - Q&A for engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of video, and media creation
- Graphic Design - Q&A for Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts
- Database Administrators - Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community
- Science Fiction & Fantasy - Q&A for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts
- Code Review - Q&A for peer programmer code reviews
- Programming Puzzles & Code Golf - Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers
- Quantitative Finance - Q&A for finance professionals and academics
- Project Management - Q&A for project managers
- Skeptics - Q&A for scientific skepticism
- Physical Fitness - Q&A for physical fitness professionals, athletes, trainers, and those providing health-related needs
- Drupal Answers - Q&A for Drupal developers and administrators
- Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair - Q&A for mechanics and DIY enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles
- Parenting - Q&A for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role
- SharePoint - Q&A for SharePoint enthusiasts
- Music: Practice & Theory - Q&A for musicians, students, and enthusiasts
- Software Quality Assurance & Testing - Q&A for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers
- Mi Yodeya - Q&A for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more
- German Language - Q&A for speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation
- Japanese Language - Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language
- Philosophy - Q&A for those interested in the study of the fundamental nature of knowledge, reality, and existence
- Gardening & Landscaping - Q&A for gardeners and landscapers
- Travel - Q&A for road warriors and seasoned travelers
- Personal Productivity - Q&A for people wanting to improve their personal productivity
- Cryptography - Q&A for software developers, mathematicians and others interested in cryptography
- Signal Processing - Q&A for practitioners of the art and science of signal, image and video processing
- French Language - Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the French language
- Christianity - Q&A for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more
- Bitcoin - Q&A for Bitcoin crypto-currency enthusiasts
- Linguistics - Q&A for professional linguists and others with an interest in linguistic research and theory
- Biblical Hermeneutics - Q&A for professors, theologians, and those interested in exegetical analysis of biblical texts
- History - Q&A for historians and history buffs
- LEGO® Answers - Q&A for LEGO® and building block enthusiasts
- Spanish Language - Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Spanish language
- Computational Science - Q&A for scientists using computers to solve scientific problems
- Movies & TV - Q&A for movie and tv enthusiasts
- Chinese Language - Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Chinese language
- Biology - Q&A for biology researchers, academics, and students
- Poker - Q&A for serious players and enthusiasts of poker
- Mathematica - Q&A for users of Wolfram Mathematica
- Cognitive Sciences - Q&A for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry
- The Great Outdoors - Q&A for people who love outdoor activities, excursions, and outdoorsmanship
- Martial Arts - Q&A for students and teachers of all martial arts
- Sports - Q&A for participants in team and individual sport activities
- Academia - Q&A for academics and those enrolled in higher education
- Computer Science - Q&A for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science
- The Workplace - Q&A for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting
- Windows Phone - Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Phone OS
- Chemistry - Q&A for scientists, academics, teachers and students
- Chess - Q&A for serious players and enthusiasts of chess
- Raspberry Pi - Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi
- Russian Language - Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Russian language
- Islam - Q&A for Muslims, experts in Islam, and those interested in learning more about Islam
- Salesforce - Q&A for Salesforce administrators, implementation experts, developers and anybody in-between
- Ask Patents - Q&A for people interested in improving and participating in the patent system
- Genealogy & Family History - Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history
- Robotics - Q&A for professional robotic engineers, hobbyists, researchers and students
- ExpressionEngine® Answers - Q&A for administrators, end users, developers and designers for ExpressionEngine® CMS
- Politics - Q&A for people interested in governments, policies, -and political processes
  Anime & Manga - Q&A for anime and manga fans
- Magento - Q&A for users of the Magento e-Commerce platform
  English Language Learners - Q&A for speakers of other languages learning English
- Sustainable Living - Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources
- Tridion - Q&A for Tridion developers and administrators
- Reverse Engineering - Q&A for researchers and developers who explore the principles of a system through analysis of its structure, function, and operation
- Network Engineering - Q&A for network engineers
- Open Data - Q&A for developers and researchers interested in open data
- Freelancing - Q&A for self-employed and freelance workers
- Blender - Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games
- MathOverflow - Q&A for professional mathematicians
  Space Exploration - Q&A for spacecraft operators, scientists, engineers, and enthusiasts
- Sound Design - Q&A for sound engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts
- Astronomy - Q&A for astronomers and astrophysicists
- Tor - Q&A for researchers, developers, and users of Tor
- Pets - Q&A for pet owners, caretakers, breeders, veterinarians, and trainers
- Amateur Radio - Q&A for amateur radio enthusiasts
- Italian Language - Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Italian language
- Stack Overflow em Português - Q&A for programadores profissionais e entusiastas
- Aviation - Q&A for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts
- Ebooks - Q&A for ebook publishers and readers
- Beer, Wine & Spirits - Q&A for alcoholic beverage aficionados and those interested in beer, wine, or spirits
- Software Recommendations - Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations
- Arduino - Q&A for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino
- Expatriates - Q&A for people living abroad on a long-term basis
- Mathematics Educators - Q&A for those involved in the field of teaching mathematics
- Earth Science - Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences
- Joomla - Q&A for Joomla! administrators, users, developers and designers
- Data Science - Q&A for Data science professionals, Machine Learning specialists, and those interested in learning more about the field
- Puzzling - Q&A for those who create, solve, and study puzzles
- Craft CMS - Q&A for administrators, end users, developers and designers for Craft CMS
- Buddhism - Q&A for people practicing or interested in Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice
- Hinduism - Q&A for followers of the Hindu religion and those interested in learning more about Hinduism
- Community Building - Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators
- Startups - Q&A for entrepreneurs faced with delivering a new product or service under conditions of significant uncertainty
- Worldbuilding - Q&A for writers/artists using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings
  „Çπ„Çø„ÉÉ„ÇØ„Éª„Ç™„Éº„Éê„Éº„Éï„É≠„Éº - Q&A for „Éó„É≠„Ç∞„É©„Éû„Éº„Å®„Éó„É≠„Ç∞„É©„Éü„É≥„Ç∞„Å´ÁÜ±ÂøÉ„ÅÆ‰∫∫
- Emacs - Q&A for those using, extending or developing Emacs
- History of Science and Mathematics - Q&A for people interested in the history and origins of science and mathematics
- Economics - Q&A for professional and academic economists and analysts
- Lifehacks - Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks
- Engineering - Q&A for professionals and students of engineering
- Coffee - Q&A for people interested in all aspects of producing and consuming coffee
- Vi and Vim - Q&A for people using the vi and Vim families of text editors
- Music Fans - Q&A for music historians, critics, and fans
- Woodworking - Q&A for professional and amateur woodworkers
- CiviCRM - Q&A for administrators and users of the CiviCRM Constituent Relationship Management software
- Health - Q&A for medical specialists, students, dietitians, and anyone with health-related questions
- Stack Overflow –Ω–∞ —Ä—É—Å—Å–∫–æ–º - Q&A for –ø—Ä–æ–≥—Ä–∞–º–º–∏—Å—Ç–æ–≤
  – —É—Å—Å–∫–∏–π —è–∑—ã–∫ - Q&A for –ª–∏–Ω–≥–≤–∏—Å—Ç–æ–≤, —ç—Ç–∏–º–æ–ª–æ–≥–æ–≤, –∏ —ç–Ω—Ç—É–∑–∏–∞—Å—Ç–æ–≤ —Ä—É—Å—Å–∫–æ–≥–æ —è–∑—ã–∫–∞
- Mythology - Q&A for enthusiasts and scholars of mythology
- Law - Q&A for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law
- Open Source - Q&A for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects
- elementary OS - Q&A for developers and users of elementary OS and applications
- Portuguese Language - Q&A for linguists, teachers and learners wanting to discuss the finer points of the Portuguese language
- Computer Graphics - Q&A for computer graphics researchers and programmers
- Hardware Recommendations - Q&A for people seeking specific hardware recommendations
- Stack Overflow en español - Q&A for programadores y profesionales de la informática
- 3D Printing - Q&A for 3D printing enthusiasts
- Ethereum - Q&A for users of Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network
- Latin Language - Q&A for linguists, teachers, and students wanting to discuss the finer points of the Latin language
- Language Learning - Q&A for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of second-language acquisition
- Retrocomputing - Q&A for vintage-computer hobbyists interested in restoring, preserving, and using the classic computer and gaming systems of yesteryear
- Arts & Crafts - Q&A for artists and crafters
- Korean Language - Q&A for linguists, teachers and students of the Korean language
- Monero - Q&A for developers and users of the secure, private and untraceable cryptocurrency Monero
- Artificial Intelligence - Q&A for people interested in conceptual questions about life and challenges in a world where "cognitive" functions can be mimicked in purely digital environment
- Esperanto Language - Q&A for teachers and students of the Esperanto language
- Sitecore - Q&A for developers and end users of the Sitecore CMS and multichannel marketing software

via (marcown modified added manually):
`curl https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic | awk '{gsub("&amp;","\\&"); gsub("<[^>]*>",""); gsub("[[:space:]][[:space:]]*", " ");} /Q&A/{print prev " -" $0} {prev=$0}'`

Comment: Related [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387354/1359324), [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/1359324)

Comment: The `„Çπ„Çø„ÉÉ ...`  and `–Ω–∞ —Ä—É— ...` nonsense entries are presumably supposed to non-english-language SO sites.  Can someone fix that up somehow?

Comment: I don't see the point of the entire list being displayed here. Or is that exactly the point, that there is not a single page where they are mentioned collectively?

Comment: Related: [The single source of truth for the site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359796)

Comment: *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)* did more than [the bare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ChQK8j6so8) [minimum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7SNEdjftno): *"Before posting a question, please read* ***What topics can I ask about here?*** *and* ***How do I ask a good question?.*** *To get you the best answers, we’ve provided some guidance: 1. Code* ***must*** *produce the desired output. 2. Code* ***must not*** *error or contain known bugs. 3. Code* ***must*** *be written or maintained by you. 4. Titles* ***should*** *describe what the code does. 5. The*..."*

Answer (score 4):

I mean we kinda do.

Stack Overflow has this:

[image: The "How to Ask" section, which appears when creating a question, asks whether the question is about programming and includes links to the Help Center.]

[image: A subtitle under the site logo states, "For professional and enthusiast programmers".]

and the others have some variation of the above depending on the site. You can also visit the Help Center (`/help`) and Tour (`/tour`)of each site if you forget.

Comment: I had never noticed that bold question in the "How to Ask" box. That is helpful. I still think it would be valid to have these standard descriptions in / and /questions/ask. I'll post an additional answer with a complete list. I think they are all very good and worth prominence.

Comment: Ummm you shouldn't. This is probably not the right place to do so

Comment: this is no longer accurate

Comment: There is a banner shown at the top of the page when you haven't joined a site (at least, when I open a site in an incognito window – not sure if it still appears when you have an account on a different SE network site but you haven't joined the current one yet). For instance, on RPG.SE, this text is shown in the banner at the top: "Role-playing Games Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for gamemasters and players of tabletop, paper-and-pencil role-playing games. It only takes a minute to sign up."

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2023,

- Stack Overflow has an entirely different homepage for users that are not logged in. Below is a screenshot. The image is very tall, so here it is shown using the "s" parameter (shows the "small" version); click to view the complete image.
  [image: Stack Overflow homepage for not logged in users]
- The "standard homepage" shows a banner showing the site scope abbreviated version of the basic site workings. Below is the screenshot corresponding to Meta Stack Exchange.
  [image: Meta Stack Exchange].
- The Ask Question form has a new design [released in 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/1359324). Each community might customize it by following the corresponding process; see [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/1359324)

Note: Don't rely on https://stackexchange.com/sites and https://data.stackexchange.com as the "one source of truth" to get the list of sites, instead use the community-curated list of sites: [How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359794/1359324).

Related

- [Make "What's on topic for this site?" visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301363/1359324) ([feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request))
- [Where can we find a site charter/purpose that tells us the types of question on/off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387354/1359324) ([discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion))